# Vuetify Date Picker - How to Set the initial date on dialog usage

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have tried using picker-date prop, and looked at the others, but I can't yet figure out how to have `<v-date-picker>` show with the year, month and day of my own choosing.  Has anyone done this and know how to manage it?  The component where the picker is used is a child component, and the date I'd like to initialize with comes in as a prop.

Comment: could you please show what you have done so far?

Comment: @KickButtowski, the following is from the template:

      <v-date-picker 
        v-model="datadate" 
        no-title 
        scrollable
        @input="menu = false"
      >
      </v-date-picker>

this is the prop coming in from the parent component:

     props: {
       dataDate: {
       type: String
       },

Comment: ...following is from the template:

`      <v-date-picker 
        v-model="datadate" 
        no-title 
        scrollable
        @input="menu = false"
      >
      </v-date-picker>
`
this is the prop coming in from the parent component:
`
     props: {
       dataDate: {
       type: String
       },
     }
`
this is the assignment of the v-model data variable from the prop:
`
  data () {
    return {
     menu: false,
     datadate: this.dataDate,
    }
`
with this pattern, the initial date of the picker is passed in from the parent.

Comment: I have not figured out yet how to show code in a comment here - maybe you can't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried with picker:'2020-06-04' initial value in v-data-picker and its showing this chosen value. Are you looking for something similar?

https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/oNbYPvv?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
{{picker}}
<v-row justify="center">
  <v-date-picker v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>
</v-row>
</v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
el: '#app',
vuetify: new Vuetify(),
data () {
return {
  picker:'2020-06-04',
  //picker: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
 }
 },
 })
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj, this demonstrates a good answer to the question regarding initial value. I am relatively new with Vue and Vuetify, and have been building my first real product that uses it over the last 4 months. I've spent (literally) a couple of weeks struggling with getting <v-date-picker> to do what I want it to do.  Having said that, on this one I have now figured out that

Comment: my comment period timed out, so here is what I was trying to reply with:

Thanks Manoj, you demonstrate a good answer to the question regarding initial value.

I have also figured out that you can use props to initialize Vue component instance data like this:
props: {
    dataDate: {
      type: String
    }
}

  data () {
    return {
      datadate: this.dataDate,
    }
  },

So when I pass in a prop to use to initialize the data picker, the invocation of <v-date-picker> can use datadate for its starting value.

Comment: my comment period timed out, so here is what I was trying to reply with:

Thanks Manoj, you demonstrate a good answer to the question regarding initial value.

I have also figured out that you can use props to initialize Vue component instance data like this:
props: {
    dataDate: {
      type: String
    }
}

  data () {
    return {
      datadate: this.dataDate,
    }
  },

So when I pass in a prop to use to initialize the data picker, the invocation of <v-date-picker> can use datadate for its starting value.

Answer (score 0):

I usually initialize the date picker with the current date minus the timezone offset like so:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="blabla">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker v-model="datePicker"></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      datePicker: (new Date(Date.now() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    }
  },
})
```